# Troubleshooting phpize script with autoconf. error when trying to configure mssql extension in PHP

Tags: php, osx-mountain-lion

I'm running Mac OS 10.8.2 and have a dev PHP (5.3.15) web server (Apache 2.2) running.  I need to access a MSSQL database for a project.  I have configured and installed FreeTDS successfully.  I just need to 'phpize' the MSSQL extension and configure it to run with FreeTDS.  When I navigate to the MSSQL directory in the terminal and try to 'phpize', I get this error:

```
Username-MacBook-Pro:mssql user$ phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
$PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.
```

Is this a common OSX error and does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: From what I can gather, the autoconf. file would normailly reside in /usr/lib/autoconf?  But with the latest release of Xcode, the autoconf file got removed.  Do any Xcoder's know if this is true?

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution, it worked for me: http://recensus.com/blog/technical/installing-autoconf-and-fixing-phpize-on-osx-10-8/